# How to configure iptables for a home router?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, iptables

I'm setting up a Raspberry PI as a home router and below is my current iptables script. The router has also

- a proxy,
- samba,
- CUPS,
- bind9,
- a WLAN access point and
- a DHCP server.

I am unsure if the setup below works, if bind cannot answer a dns requst: Do I have to make it possible to open a "NEW" connection on port 53 in the output chain? Or do I have to put it in the FORWARD chain, because the LAN-client does the upstream request rather than bind.

The router shall get an IP (for the WAN interface) via DHCP from my ISP. The router shall also distribute IPs for the (W)LAN clients. Do I have to allow udp port 67/68 on all interfaces for both input and output chain for this?

Is there a way to make my script shorter, i.e. get the same result while improving the readability? My basic aim is to provide the installed services (see above) to (W)LAN clients and give (W)LAN clients access to HTTP(s), IMAP(s), SMTP, NTP and WhatsApp.

```
#!/bin/sh
log() {
 echo "$(date '+%b %d %H:%M:%S') $(hostname) iptablesInit: $1"
 echo "$(date '+%b %d %H:%M:%S') $(hostname) iptablesInit: $1" >> /var/log/iptablesInit.log
}

IPT="/sbin/iptables"

WAN="WAN"
LAN="LAN"
WLAN="WLAN"

# Flush all chaines
log 'Flush everything...'
$IPT -F
$IPT -X
$IPT -t mangle -F
$IPT -t mangle -X
$IPT -t nat -F
$IPT -t nat -X

$IPT -F INPUT
$IPT -F FORWARD
$IPT -F OUTPUT
log 'Flush done'

# unlimited
$IPT -A INPUT  -i lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# set policies
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P OUTPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP

# NAT
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ${WAN} -j MASQUERADE

#===== BLOCK =====
# Block sync
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${WAN} -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW  -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "Drop Sync"
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${WAN} -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP

# Block Fragments
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${WAN} -f  -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "Fragments Packets"
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${WAN} -f -j DROP

# Block bad stuff
$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${WAN} -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN,URG,PSH -j DROP
$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${WAN} -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP

$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${WAN} -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "NULL Packets"
$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${WAN} -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP # NULL packets

$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${WAN} -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP

$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${WAN} -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "XMAS Packets"
$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${WAN} -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP #XMAS

$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${WAN} -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "Fin Packets Scan"
$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${WAN} -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DROP # FIN packet scans

$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${WAN} -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL SYN,RST,ACK,FIN,URG -j DROP

# Block CUPS WAN access
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o ${WAN} -p tcp --dport 631 -j REJECT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o ${WAN} -p udp --dport 631 -j REJECT

#===== ALLOW =====
# Allow full connection but no incomming stuff between LAN and router
#$IPT -A INPUT  -i ${LAN} -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
#$IPT -A OUTPUT -o ${LAN} -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow ssh 
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${LAN}  -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o ${LAN} -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# allow ICMP ping pong stuff
$IPT -A INPUT  -i ${LAN}  -p icmp -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o ${LAN}  -p icmp -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT  -i ${WLAN} -p icmp -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o ${WLAN} -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# Allow port 53 tcp/udp (DNS Server)
$IPT -A INPUT  -p tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED  -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A INPUT  -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A INPUT  -p tcp --dport 953 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED  -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 953 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Proxy
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${LAN}  -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${WLAN} -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT

#DHCP
$IPT -A INPUT -p udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT

# Open port 631 for CUPS/Printing
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${LAN}  -p tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${LAN}  -p udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${WLAN} -p tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${WLAN} -p udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT

# Samba
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 139,445 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dport 137,138 -j ACCEPT

#===== FORWARD =====
# HTTP(s)
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${LAN} -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${LAN} -p udp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${LAN} -o ${WAN} -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${LAN} -o ${WAN} -p udp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${WLAN} -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${WLAN} -p udp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WLAN} -o ${WAN} -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WLAN} -o ${WAN} -p udp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# IMAP(s)
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${LAN} -p tcp -m multiport --dport 143,993 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${LAN} -p udp -m multiport --dport 143,993 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${LAN} -o ${WAN} -p tcp -m multiport --dport 143,993 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${LAN} -o ${WAN} -p udp -m multiport --dport 143,993 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${WLAN} -p tcp -m multiport --dport 143,993 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${WLAN} -p udp -m multiport --dport 143,993 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WLAN} -o ${WAN} -p tcp -m multiport --dport 143,993 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WLAN} -o ${WAN} -p udp -m multiport --dport 143,993 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# SMTP
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${LAN} -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${LAN} -p udp --dport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${LAN} -o ${WAN} -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${LAN} -o ${WAN} -p udp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${WLAN} -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${WLAN} -p udp --dport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WLAN} -o ${WAN} -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WLAN} -o ${WAN} -p udp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# NTP
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${LAN} -p udp --dport 123 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED  -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${LAN} -o ${WAN} -p udp --dport 123 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED  -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${WLAN} -p udp --dport 123 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED  -j ACCEPT 
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WLAN} -o ${WAN} -p udp --dport 123 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED  -j ACCEPT 
# WhatsApp
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${LAN} -p tcp --dport 5222 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${LAN} -o ${WAN} -p tcp --dport 5222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${WLAN} -p tcp --dport 5222 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WLAN} -o ${WAN} -p tcp --dport 5222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Reject (W)LAN Traffic rather than drop
$IPT -A INPUT   -i ${LAN}  -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
$IPT -A INPUT   -i ${WLAN} -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${LAN}  -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ${WLAN} -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
$IPT -A OUTPUT             -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

exit 0
```

Comment: Your script is filled with so many redundancies I hardly know where to start!

Comment: Why not install [LEDE](https://lede-project.org/toh/start?dataflt%5BModel*~%5D=raspberry) and make it far easier on yourself?  Otherwise you may want to take a look at [FirewallBuilder](http://www.fwbuilder.org/index.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Your entire DNS section, delete it I have replace the whole INPUT section for you.  Delete your DHCP 67,68 its now cover by related,established.

```
IPT -I INPUT 1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


IPT -I FORWARD 1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Now erase all the other commands that contain RELATED,ESTABLISHED in your forward chain.  Then are now all redundant, which basically means all of the other commands.

Your code

```
# Open port 631 for CUPS/Printing
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${LAN}  -p tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${LAN}  -p udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${WLAN} -p tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${WLAN} -p udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT

# Samba
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 139,445 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dport 137,138 -j ACCEPT
```

---

New code for INPUT chain.

```
$IPT -N INTERNET
$IPT -I INPUT 1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -I INPUT -d <internet ip> -j INTERNET
$IPT -I INTERNET <add ports and protocols here from internet>
## insert **block bad** here
# Change INPUT to INTERNET for the chain in block bad
$IPT -I INTERNET -j drop


## You may want to add $IPT -A INPUT  -d <internet IP> -j DROP
## so random internet people can connect to 139,445,631
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 139,445,631 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dport 137,138,631 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -j drop
```

---

Anything not accepted is dropped.